# How to get total number of table elements having ID inside a DIV tag using Selenium Webdriver and C#

Tags: c#-4.0, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I get the total number of table elements having ID inside a DIV tag using Selenium Webdriver and C#?

Expected Output: I need output as "Number of Table ID = 2 "

```
 <form id="form1"> 
   <div class="sec_container_pop">  
   <div class="sec_header_pop"> Item Details </div> 
   <table class="subheader">
   <div class="spacerdiv"/> 
   <div style="width: 900px; height: 400px; overflow-x: auto; position: relative; overflow-y: auto;">
   <table class="reportscontent_pop" style="width: 880px"> 
   <table id="tItemDetails0" class="reportscontent_pop" style="width: 880px; display: none;"> 
   <table class="reportscontent_pop" style="width: 880px"> 
   <table id="tItemDetails1" class="reportscontent_pop" style="width: 880px; display: none;"> 
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there any id or className for div tag? If you can write xpath for div tag, then get the WebElement from that xpath and use that WebElement to retrieve all the table element using webElement.findElements(By.tagName("table"));. This will return the list of table elements.

Comment: `<form id="form1">
<div class="sec_container_pop">
<div class="sec_header_pop">             Item Details         </div>
<table class="subheader">
<div class="spacerdiv"/>
<div style="width: 900px; height: 400px; overflow-x: auto; position: relative; overflow-y: auto;">
<table class="reportscontent_pop" style="width: 880px">
<table id="tItemDetails0" class="reportscontent_pop" style="width: 880px; display: none;">
<table class="reportscontent_pop" style="width: 880px">
<table id="tItemDetails1" class="reportscontent_pop" style="width: 880px; display: none;">
</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='form1']/div[4]"));

//Get list of table elements using tagName
List<WebElement> list = webElement.findElements(By.tagName("table"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much Saritha, this helped me. But had a small change      Changed to : `IList<IWebElement> tableID = webDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("//form[@id='form1']/div/div[3]/table[@id]"));`

Comment: Hoo...I have written in Java.

Answer (score 0):

XPath:

```
IList<IWebElement> tableIDs = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div/table[@id]"));

Console.WriteLine("Number of Table ID = {0}", tableIDs.Count);
```

Css:

```
IList<IWebElement> tableIDs = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div>table[id]"));

Console.WriteLine("Number of Table ID = {0}", tableIDs.Count);
```